# Using boost preprocessor to call a variadic template iteratively

Tags: c++, boost, macros, boost-preprocessor

Assume I have a variadic template:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Foo;
```

This variadic template generates another template recursively until it reaches the one argument `Foo` in the last level. Now I want to have a macro for example `Bar(...)` which when I call it I get something like this:

```
Bar(float, int, string, vector<int>)
// expands to
Macro(Foo<float, int, string, vector<int>>)
Macro(Foo<int, string, vector<int>>)
Macro(Foo<string, vector<int>>)
Macro(Foo<vector<int>>)
```

Which `Macro(...)` is another macro for doing something on this class. I hope to able to use Boost Preprocessor to reduce the code I have to write.

Please suggest me some tips that helps me to write such macro.

Comment: That's possible for sure, but this seriously sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Are `Bar` and `Macro` different macros? And do you want the `Macro` macro to be called for each call expansion of the variadic template?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Although I were not agree with you completely, but I changed the question to avoid to look an XY problem.

Comment: @nabla The answer for both of your questions is yes. They are different and the `Macro` must call for each version.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/302b91db793b1c83) seems to work, but I doubt it's the best way to approach this problem. Adding the [tag:boost-preprocessor] tag may help your answer reach an expert in the library.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and solution. Currently I could not check this inside my main project but it seems that works. I will check this soon and tell you about the solution.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz  I think [this slight variation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7776eec1c86fa0ff) makes a little more sense.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I had not access to my source codes. I checked your solution and it works very well. Thanks for your solution. If you would write this as an answer I could check this as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach to solving your problem but this does what you want:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define CALL_MACRO(_,__,SEQ) Macro(Foo<BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(SEQ)>)

#define GENERATE_MACRO_INVOCATIONS(SEQS) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(CALL_MACRO,_,SEQS)

#define GENERATE_DESCENDING_SEQUENCES(_,INDEX,DATA) (BOOST_PP_SEQ_REST_N(INDEX,DATA))

#define BAR_IMPL(SEQ) GENERATE_MACRO_INVOCATIONS(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(0,BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(SEQ),GENERATE_DESCENDING_SEQUENCES, SEQ))


#define Bar(...) BAR_IMPL(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

Bar(float, int, string, vector<int>)
```

- You initially have a variadic data: `float, int, string, vector<int>`.
- `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ` transforms it to: `(float)(int)(string)(vector<int>)`
- `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO` calls the macro `GENERATE_DESCENDING_SEQUENCES` `BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(SEQ)` times with the sequence as data and an index that starts from 0.
- `BOOST_PP_SEQ_REST_N(INDEX,DATA)` removes the `INDEX` first elements from `DATA` and returns the rest. This result is put inside a couple of parentheses.
- After the invocation of the REPEAT you have a sequence of sequences:

  **(**(float)(int)(string)(vector)**)(**(int)(string)(vector)**)(**(string)(vector)**)(**(vector)**)**
- `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` calls `CALL_MACRO` with every element in the sequence of sequences.
- And finally `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM` takes a sequence and returns its elements separated by commas.

[**Preprocessed on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7776eec1c86fa0ff)

Answer (score 1):

Update: Edited answer based on comments. Now calls `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS` macro instead of the `macro()` function I defined. I did not test this with the `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS`, however, I did a simulation by accessing the type of `Foo<...>` at each level of the template expansion. I was able to access each of the different types for the different expansions, so I assume that whatever `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS` does should work.

I think that this now does what you want:

```
#define BAR(...) Foo<__VA_ARGS__>()

// Variadic definition of Foo
template <typename... Args>
struct Foo;

// Specialize Foo for the case that there is at least on template parameter
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct Foo<Arg, Args...> : Foo<Args...> {
  using type = Foo<Arg, Args...>;
  Foo() : Foo<Args...>(){
    BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS(type)
  }
};

// Terminating case for Foo
template <>
struct Foo<> {
  using type = Foo<>;
  Foo() { BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS(type) }
};

int main() {
  BAR(int, float, double);
}
```

To test that this should theoretically work, I defined the following macro:

```
#define MACRO(x) test<x>();
```

And replaced `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS(type)` with `MACRO(type)`. The function `test` is the following:

```
template <typename T>
void test() {
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
}
```

Running the code printed the following (I've added the comments), which shows that the templates are expanded in the macro and should appear to `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS` as is shown in the question:

```
3FooIJEE      // Foo<>
3FooIJdEE     // Foo<double>
3FooIJfdEE    // Foo<float, double>
3FooIJifdEE   // Foo<int, float, double>
```

Here is a live demo of the code [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fbc169c8f3dccc8).

One thing to note is that the expansion is in the opposite direction to what the OP specified, i.e:

```
Macro(Foo<>)
Macro(Foo<double>)
Macro(Foo<float, double>)
Macro(Foo<int, float, double>)
```

Comment: May be I must tell more about `Macro`, it is another macro that I have to use. Specifically, this is the `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS` macro which I want to use to export each type of class. So I think your answer is not valid, it is a template and did not what I wanted.

Comment: @nabla You're assuming `Macro` is something that can be reduced to a function (`constexpr` or otherwise) which seems not to be the case for the OP. `Macro` could expand to a declaration for example.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz, sorry, I made an assumption based on what I understood from the question. Please see updated answer -- hopefully this does what you want. As I didn't try it with boost, please let me know if it works.

Comment: @Elektito, yes, that was my mistake. Please see the updated answer -- I think that this does what the OP wants.

Comment: @nabla Thanks for your considerations. But still I think your solution is not correct. Because you call the macro inside constructor, the macro that I worked with is a macro that declares another classes so it never be able to call inside a constructor. Your solution is valid just when we want do this with a function not a macro for declaration.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz I disagree, this should do exactly what you asked for. I don't see why it matters that the macro is called in the constructor.

Comment: Assume this macro declares a new class(e.g. `#define Macro(name) class name{}`) so in this situation it could not be inside a constructor.